# Read a datagridview in another class than main one

Tags: c#, winforms, function, class, datagridview

I have a form with datagridview and I want to use it in another class, to export the data from it.

I have this function for exporting:

```
public void exportWebsite(DataGridView gridIn, string outputFile)
{
    //test to see if the DataGridView has any rows
    if (gridIn.RowCount > 0)
    {
        string value = "";
        DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
        StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(outputFile);

        swOut.Write(gridIn.Columns[9].HeaderText);

        swOut.WriteLine();

        //write DataGridView rows to csv
        for (int j = 0; j <= gridIn.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (j > 0)
            {
                swOut.WriteLine();
            }

            dr = gridIn.Rows[j];


            if (dr.Cells[9].Value.ToString() == " " || dr.Cells[9].Value.ToString() == null || dr.Cells[9].Value.ToString() == "")
            {
                value = " ";
            }
            else
            {
                value = dr.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
            }
            swOut.Write(value);

        }
        swOut.Close();
    }
}
```

That is in the same class of the Form, but I want to do the exporting from an "external" class, different than the main one. How can I call the datagridview there? I tried using perimeter "DataGridView dgv" in the class definition, but it doesn't exist such thing.

So, my question is how can I pass the datagridview to another class other than the main one?

Answer (score 0):

For example to want to export using a button.

On your main class:

```
private void yourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        YourExternalClass yec = new YourExternalClass();
        yec.ExportDataGridView(YourDataGridView);
}
```

And on your external class:

```
public void ExportDataGridView(DataGridView dgv){
//add you code here for exporting
}
```

Make sure you import references that are needed on your external class, and your method must be a public one.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. There is no "DataGridView" type in the external class that I can use as perimeter.

Comment: Can you give me snippet or screenshot of your external class? Your external class must implement Forms.

Answer (score -1):

private void yourButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

CustomExternalClass CEC = new CustomExternalClass ();

CEC.ExportDataGridViewData(dgv);

}

while in CustomExternalClass you need to specify full namespace path in parameter, it may also need to give reference path for Datagridview dll path from GAC

public void ExportDataGridViewData(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataGridView dgv)
{

//Export code here

}

Comment: That is pretty much the same solution as the other answer, which does not work. Have you tested it?

Comment: Specify your Code snippets here